# Import C# public key to java to verify

Tags: c#, java, rsa, sha512

I create a pub/priv key pair in C#, i want to sign it in C# then verify it in Java.
How do i do that using SHA512withRSA?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily exchange by through JNI interface.

Review the sample:

[csharp-in-java](http://arunkumarnonascii.blogspot.in/2011/12/csharp-in-java.html)

[csharpin-java-ii-string-handling](http://arunkumarnonascii.blogspot.in/2012/01/csharpin-java-ii-string-handling.html)

Meanwhile have to improve by objects handling in JNI call.